# I am trying to write a program where it the inputs from a google form will match with a list in spreadsheet,and add the quantities together

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to match 2 variables(one taken from form submission and one is in the data base),and then add their quantities together. Is there any tips or advise on it?

Initially I tried doing it the opposite way. Which was having the list(over 2000 things) search the data from form submissions and then add it together. I realize that it will be too laggy that way,thus this solution,but i have no idea how I can start on it.

```
 if(input1 == database1){
var qty_database1 = qty_database1 + qty_input1 ;

}

 if(input1 == database2){
var qty_database2 = qty_database2 + qty_input1 ;

}
```

By doing this way,I will have to make each of the 35 inputs(all from form submission,not all 35 might have values) check against 2000+ variables(taken from the data base),which is not effective.I tried searching around on the web but cant seem to find what i need.

Here is the link :[Spreadsheet of data collected](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t3-AD8A0i4MZLWPh9PIR9CZYYkzb3vz2u2nNKcQPY2g/edit?usp=sharing)
"Total Defects by departments" is the database,where all information will be stored.
The other tabs are all 3 form submissions spreadsheets.
If there is a similar "S No." & "ID No." in the 1st/2nd/3rd AQL,it will only take the last set of values,in the order of 3rd,2nd & lastly 1st.

Comment: Does this help? @Andreas

Comment: Hi. _Does this help?_ To be honest - No. you mention a list of 2000 "things" and 35 inputs. This example doesn't explain the bigger picture, nor how you have obtained values for input1, example1, example2, qty_example1, qty_input1, qty_example2 or qty_input2. You have to explain the whole scenario. If you have a spreadsheet, then sharing the spreadsheet would also help.

Comment: Updated the information.Sry..

Comment: 1) Total Defects = 5 sets of three columns. Why not one set of three columns? 2) Dept/Defect duplicates:Col A/B: OL_F_ENG,55 - Tent Broken; OL_CM_DM_O,74 - Dishdown;Col D/E: IL_STRIP,86 - Common Space ULL; OL_PP_DEV,86 - Common Space ULL;OL_PP_DEV,180 - PTH Void;Col G/H: OL_CM_DM_O,254 - Gold Scratch; OL_CM_OSP,254 - Gold Scratch; OL_CM_STRP,254 - Gold Scratch;OL_ME_ROUT,254 - Gold Scratch; OL_ME_VCUT,254 - Gold Scratch; OL_F_ENG,313 - Pad Undersized; OL_QA_IQC,334 - Measling;Col J/K: OL_QA_AQL,460 - Arrow Left;Col M/N: OL_SHIP,476 - Oxidation;Total net unique Dept/Defect combinations = 2,109.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer may seem unduly long but the two key lines are:

- `var defectcodes = defectvalues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });`
- `var c = defectcodes.indexOf(respcode);`

The OP receives form submissions reporting defects. There are three forms, and each response can include information for up to 35 separate defects. Defect information comprises six fields, but for the sake of this exercise there are three key fields: "department", "defect type" and the number of defects. The OP's goal is to report defect information, in a separate sheet ("Total Defects"), showing the total number of defects for each department/defect combination. There are over 2,100 department/defect combinations arranged in five sets of three columns (Department, Defect and Qty).

The OP's problem is the matching of the "department" and "defect" from the form responses sheets.

There are several elements essential to this proposed solution:

- **Change the layout of the "Total Defects" sheet.**
  The five column-set layout is an unnecessary complication. The layout should be simplified into a single column-set of 2100 rows.
- **Simplify the search/match.**
  Instead of matching two separate values ("Department" and "Defect"), create a single unique code by concatenating those values, and use this for the search/match.
- **Use the Javascript methods of 'map' and 'indexof' to simplify processing.**

In the following answer, I have focused on the essentials of the solution. I have not added code to automatically loop through the three form response sheets, nor to update the quantity; these are red herrings. I have left a number of Logger statements in the code to assist the OP (and others) in troubleshooting and/or understanding the code.

---

```
function so5652371304() {

  // setup Defects spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "TotalDefects02";
  var defectsheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Defect sheet name "+defectsheet.getName());//DEBUG
  var defectlastrow = defectsheet.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the last defect row = "+defectlastrow);//DEBUG

  // Layout on Total Defects is:
  // Row#1 = Header
  // Column A = Department
  // Column B = Defect
  // Column C = Concatenate Column A and Column B
  // Column D = Qty

  var defectrange = defectsheet.getRange(2,3,defectlastrow-1);// column 3 (C)- dept+code
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the defect range is "+defectrange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG
  var defectvalues = defectrange.getValues();

  // apply the "map" method to assign the row number to every element
  var defectcodes = defectvalues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });

  // set up the response sheets
  var respsheetname = "1st AQL";// 1st AQL// 2nd AQL // 3rd AQL
  var respsheet =  ss.getSheetByName(respsheetname);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Response sheet name "+respsheet.getName());//DEBUG
  var resplastrow = respsheet.getLastRow();
  var resplastcolumn = respsheet.getLastColumn();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Response lastrow = "+resplastrow+", last column"+resplastcolumn); //DEBUG

  // Layout on Total Defects is:
  // Row#1 & 2 = Header
  // Column A to Q (Inclusive) = Irrelevant information (Column 1 to 17 inclusive)
  // Column R to W = Response dataset#1
  // Column R (18) = Department#1
  // Column S (19) = Defect#1
  // Column T (20) = Quantity
  // Column U (21) = Irrelevant
  // Column V (22) = Irrelevant
  // Column W (23) = Irreelvant
  // Column X (24) to HR (226) consists of a further 34 possible defect notices, each of 6 columns
  var resprange = respsheet.getRange(3,18,resplastrow-2,resplastcolumn-18+1);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the resp range is "+resprange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG
  var respvalues = resprange.getValues();

  // set Response variables
  var repliesperrow=35;
  var columnsperreply = 6;

  //Loop through replies to find matches in the database
  for (var r = 0;r<resplastrow-2;r++){//loop rows
    for (var i=0; i<repliesperrow;i++){//loop per reply
      if (respvalues[r][(i*columnsperreply)].length>0){
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: dept = "+respvalues[r][(i*columnsperreply)]+", defect = "+respvalues[r][((i*columnsperreply)+1)]+", qty = "+respvalues[r][(i*columnsperreply)+2]); //DEBUG
        var respcode = respvalues[r][(i*columnsperreply)].concat('',respvalues[r][((i*columnsperreply)+1)]);  
        var c = defectcodes.indexOf(respcode); 
        // if c=-1 then the code is not in TotalDefects Table
        // if c>-1 then the code IS in the TotalDefects Table, AND the relevant row number of the matching code  = c+2
        if (c > -1) {
          Logger.log("DEBUG: r:"+r+", i:"+i+", c="+c+", Code:"+respcode+" found in the defects database on row:"+(c+2)); // DEBUG the details are on (c+2) rows
        } else {
          Logger.log("DEBUG: r:"+r+", i:"+i+", c="+c+", Code:"+respcode+" NOT found in the defects database"); //DEBUG
        }
      }
      else{
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Layout-TotalDefects sheet**

[image: Layout-TotalDefects sheet]

---

**UPDATE:**

This revision loops through the sheets, and updates the Total Defects quantity. Rather than using (the expensive) setValue() for each new quantity value, the code accumulates the qty value and then writes a single setValues at the end of each response sheet.

Note that there are Logger statements that can be displayed for:

- Successful responses
- Unsuccessful responses (where the concatenated code could not be found in Total Defects. One might suggest to the OP that these should be written to an error sheet to simplify troubleshooting.

---

```
function so5652371306() {

  // setup Defects spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "TotalDefects06";
  var defectsheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Defect sheet name "+defectsheet.getName());//DEBUG
  var defectlastrow = defectsheet.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the last defect row = "+defectlastrow);//DEBUG


  // Layout on Total Defects is:
  // Row#1 = Header
  // Column A = Department
  // Column B = Defect
  // Column C = Concatenate Column A and Column B
  // Column D = Qty


  // get 2 x ranges and data
  // defectrange = enables the code to access the existing value of the qty
  var defectrange = defectsheet.getRange(2,3,defectlastrow-1,2);// column C - dept+code // column D = qty
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the defect range is "+defectrange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG
  var defectvalues = defectrange.getValues();
  // defectqtyrange = enables the code to increment the qty andf then, as the last command, paste the adjusted values back onto the spreadsheet
  // this avoids setValue within the Response loops.
  var defectqtyrange = defectsheet.getRange(2,4,defectlastrow-1,1);// column D - qty
  var defectqtyvalues = defectqtyrange.getValues();

  // apply the "map" method to assign the row number to every element
  var defectcodes = defectvalues.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });

  // set up an array of response sheets
  var respsheetname = [
        '1st AQL',
        '2nd AQL',
        '3rd AQL'
    ];

  // Layout of Response Sheets is:
  // Row#1 & 2 = Header
  // Column A to Q (Inclusive) = Irrelevant information (Column 1 to 17 inclusive)
  // Column R to W = Response dataset#1
  // Column R (18) = Department#1
  // Column S (19) = Defect#1
  // Column T (20) = Quantity
  // Column U (21) = Irrelevant
  // Column V (22) = Irrelevant
  // Column W (23) = Irreelvant
  // Column X (24) to HR (226) consists of a further 34 possible defect notices, each of 6 columns


  // set Response variables
  var repliesperrow = 35;
  var columnsperreply = 6;


  // loop through the response sheets
  for (var t = 0; t < respsheetname.length; t++) {

    var respsheet=ss.getSheetByName(respsheetname[t]);
    var thissheet = respsheet.getName();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Response sheet name "+thissheet);//DEBUG
    var resplastrow = respsheet.getLastRow();
    var resplastcolumn = respsheet.getLastColumn();
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: Response lastrow = "+resplastrow+", last column"+resplastcolumn); //DEBUG

    // define the range
    var resprange = respsheet.getRange(3,18,resplastrow-2,resplastcolumn-18+1);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the resp range is "+resprange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG

    // get the response data
    var respvalues = resprange.getValues();

    //Loop through replies to find matches in the database
    for (var r = 0;r<resplastrow-2;r++){//loop rows

      for (var i=0; i<repliesperrow;i++){//loop per reply

        if (respvalues[r][(i*columnsperreply)].length>0){

          var respcode = respvalues[r][(i*columnsperreply)].concat('',respvalues[r][((i*columnsperreply)+1)]);  
          var c = defectcodes.indexOf(respcode); 

          // if c=-1 then the code is not in TotalDefects Table
          // if c>-1 then the code IS in the TotalDefects Table, AND the relevant row number of the matching code  = c+2
          if (c > -1) {
            // display this for the successful matches
            //Logger.log("DEBUG: RESPONSE FOUND IN THE DATABASE. \nSheet:"+thissheet+", response row:"+(+r+1)+", response#:"+(+i+1)+", indexOf:"+c+", Code:"+respcode+", Qty:"+respvalues[r][(i*columnsperreply)+2]); // DEBUG the details are on (c+2) rows

            // display this for matching row in the Total Defects
            //Logger.log("DEBUG: Corresponding Defect. Code:"+defectvalues[c][0]+", Qty:"+defectvalues[c][1]+", SpreadsheetRow:"+(+c+2));

            // increment the adjusted Total Defect quantity
            defectqtyvalues[c][0] = Number(defectqtyvalues[c][0])+Number(respvalues[r][(i*columnsperreply)+2]);       

          } else {
            // display this for failed matches
            // Logger.log("DEBUG: Response: Code not found in Total Defects. \nSheet:"+thissheet+", response row:"+(+r+1)+", response#:"+(+i+1)+", Code:"+respcode); //DEBUG
          }
        }
        else{
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    // update the defect range with the adjusted qty
    defectqtyrange.setValues(defectqtyvalues);
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Will test it out and add what else that has to be added.Will let u know after it is all done.Thx for all your help @Tedinoz

Comment: My curiosity got the better of me. This UPDATE loops through the sheets, calculates updated quantities, and writes quantity values to the spreadsheet

Comment: Repliesperrow is just the number of columns for that row,but for columnsperreply, its the number of rows of data right? Cause the amount of rows of data will increase over time,i changed it to 

var columnsperreply = columnsperreply.getLastRow(); but it says cannot call method

Comment: `repliesperrow` is **NOT** the number of columns per row. It is the potential number of "inputs" ("each of the 35 inputs" as you indicated in your question); it will create 35 loops on each row, so that every (potential) response can be evaluated. `columnsperreply` defines the number of columns in an "input" (Department, Defect Code, Qty, Decision, Remarks). `resplastcolumn` handles the number of rows of data. You should be able to add many hundrreds of new rows (just put some dummy data in Col R, S, T) and it will cope.

Comment: Oh.So the "6" represents the number of columns per "input",i see.Thx for clarifying it.

Comment: Apologies. I documented the layout of the response sheet; I just forgot to include a comment to specifically describe the function of the those variables.

Comment: Is it also possible for it to sort only those in the past week. Like using var dateend = new date(); and var datestart = dateend - 7; or referring to a fixed cell position to get the date start and end,as showed in the "Total Defects" tab

Comment: Something like that could be done but, even with a Time-driven event trigger, I'd be concerned about over/under statement of "Total Defects". Maybe recording the last row processed (per Sheet), and then picking at lastrow+1 might be an alternative. You haven't described how many rows of data you have, or inputs per row - as a matter of interest, how long does this code take to update "Total Defects" using your live data? On a tangent, with a different layout to "Total Defects", have you considered whether the totals could be calculated using arrayformula/query/filter/whatever function?

Comment: There will be around 40 new rows on average per data sheet per day,and up to 35 inputs per row.Though there are some data sheets that has less columns as compared to "AQL". As of now,it takes around 10 sec to run,with the current amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want a pivot table of the values in your form responses. Try highlighting your data, and go to data > pivot table, and play with it there. I don't think you want a scripted function here at all.

Comment: I cant get it to show the data i want,so i guess cant then,thx thou

Comment: For defects like OL_F_ENG 55 - Tent Broken & OL_F.ENG 55 - Tent Broken,it means different things,according to the user I am doing this for.

I felt 1 set of three columns will make it too long,but i can change it to that.

Comment: If "Department" and "Defect" are meaningful values, then it's very difficult to understand how, say, two users, could distinguish which of the two relates to one and which to the other. So far as your database is concerned, they are simply values and there is nothing to distinguish how the code could/would distinguish between them.

Comment: "Defects" are the main part,it can be told apart based of their unique codes(the number before them). "Department" is just where it falls under in the company im interning at,but that is just additional info.

Comment: Im trying like a matching format,where the input will match with a "Defect" and add the quantities together in the cell to the right